# Webpack bundle doesn't get built with 'webpack serve' command

Tags: webpack

I'm trying to set up webpack-dev-server for Webpack 5 to reload my page upon bundle changes.

```
"webpack": "^5.38.1",
"webpack-cli": "^4.7.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
```

My webpack config file

```
module.exports = {
    entry: __dirname + '/public/home/src/index.jsx',
    devServer: {
      historyApiFallback: true,
      contentBase: __dirname + '/public/home/dist',
      publicPath: __dirname + '/public/home/dist',
      open: true,
      compress: true,
      hot: true,
      port: 3000,
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: [/\.jsx$/],
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: ['@babel/preset-react', '@babel/preset-env']
            }
          }
        },
        {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
        }
      ]
    },
    output: {
      filename: 'bundle.js',
      path: __dirname + '/public/home/dist'
    },
};
```

According to the docs to run webpack-dev-server it is with `webpack serve`. I'm running webpack via CLI this command `webpack serve --mode=development` and while it says built and code generated, my bundle file isn't updated (I can tell by the date modified property of the bundle file and the fact that my page doesn't update). It just never seems to compile my bundle. Now, when I run `webpack --watch --mode=development` then my bundle builds successfully but obviously I lose the hot reload of my page. What am I missing here?

Comment: I have the same problem, can't find an answer to this. Did you manage to make it work ?